# Can you use a React state which contains string data in an element?

Tags: reactjs, box-api, react-state

I am new to learning React and I am attempting to integrate Box api into my app using OAUTH 2.0. I have figured out how to implement the api to return a token but I am having trouble passing that token into my Content Explorer element. I am using state and if possible I want to pass the state (which contains the token string) into the Content Explorer element but it does not seem to work. It will render the token on the screen as a string and it will console log the token but it will not pass into the explorer element. Here is my code:

```
class Box extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            accessToken: ''
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const authenticationUrl = "https://api.box.com/oauth2/token";
        let search = window.location.search;
        let params = new URLSearchParams(search);
        let accessToken = await axios.post(
            authenticationUrl,
            queryString.stringify({
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                code: params.get('code'),
                client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                client_secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            })
        )
            .then(response => response.data.access_token);
        this.setState({accessToken: accessToken});
        console.log(accessToken);
    }


    render() {
        let token = this.state.accessToken;
        return(
            <div>
                <IntlProvider locale="en">
                    <ContentExplorer
                        contentPreviewProps={{
                            contentSidebarProps: {
                                detailsSidebarProps: {
                                    hasProperties: true,
                                    hasNotices: true,
                                    hasAccessStats: true,
                                    hasClassification: true,
                                    hasRetentionPolicy: true,
                                },
                                // features: FEATURES,
                                hasActivityFeed: true,
                                hasMetadata: true,
                                hasSkills: true,
                                hasVersions: true,
                            },
                        }}
                        // features={FEATURES}
                        rootFolderId="XXXXXXXX"
                        token={token}
                    />
                </IntlProvider>
                <h1>{token}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Box;
```

Comment: This isn't specifically related to your question, but there's a security flaw in your implementation that I want to make sure you're aware of. Your client_secret, which isn't meant to be shared, will visible to any user of your React app. The call to `oauth2/token` is really something that should happen server-side (where the client secret can be protected) and made available to your React app through an API.

Comment: Thanks! So does this mean that I should create a separate file outside of the scope of my React app that uses express/node to do this call and then have my React app read and parse this file? If so should I do the entire call or just store my client secret as a txt and parse it in?

Comment: Everything is alright. Try checking `ComponentExplorer` again and double-check how you consume `token` in them.

Comment: After further research.. is it possible and considered a good practice to have the client secret stored in docker and then have the react app pull that data to use?

Comment: If I am consuming token as a state that has been initiated and set to a value from all within the same component would that be ok?

Comment: After further investigation it looks as if the Content Explorer element is attempting to do it things before the accessToken state is set. How would I make it so that content explorer will render after accessToken is set with the token?

Answer (score 1):

The token is being parsed as a prop to the ContentExplorer component correctly from what I can see.

How are you trying to access the token in ContentExplorer?

If the component is written the same way as your Box component, you should be able to access it using;

```
this.props.token
```

Comment: I have everything in the same component called Box. My accessToken variable inside of the componentDidMount function should be the token I need once the code runs. I then use setState to pass the data in that variable into my declared state. In render I let token = this.state.accessToken and then attempt to pass the token into the Content Explorer with token={token}